# whether different CIDR Block in VPC will be priced differenty

Tags: amazon-web-services

whether different CIDR Block in VPC  will be priced differenty , for example if 10.0.0.1/28 and 10.0.0.1/16 will be priced differently due to varying ipaddress whether we can size to it maximum capacity during a initial launch . what is the advantage of assigning lower ipaddress range initally.

Answer (score 3):

There is [no cost per IP range](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/). The reason you would want to use different IP ranges would be if you want to use VPC peering between VPCs, or connect your company network to the VPC. If that's the case you would need to make sure the IP ranges between the networks don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cost associated with creating a basic VPC at all, regardless of the CIDR range used.

There are costs for additional specific VPC services such as the NAt Gateway, additional network interfaces, etc.

See https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/

I create all VPCs with a 10.0.0.x/16 range, even for small implementations. Once created you can not resize the VPC.

Comment: Creating multiple VPCs with the same CIDR block can become an issue if you ever want to use VPC peering in the future. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Good point. I should have said 10.0.0.x/16,where x is unique for each VPC, especially for multiple accounts within the same. organization.

Comment: @RodrigoM I think you mean 10.x.0.0/16 or even 10.0.x.0/24 rather than 10.0.0.x/16.